# Как узнать координаты определенного блока относительно всего документа при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Как узнать координаты определенного блока относительно всего документа при помощи `JS`? Есть, конечно, методы `getBoundingClientRect()` и `getClientRect()`, но они определяют координаты относительно окна. Т.е. при скролле координаты меняются.

Comment: __Просто я тупой__ no comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути, для того, чтобы получить положение элемента относительно всего документа нужно знать положение элемента относительно окна и скролл страницы по осям (`pageYOffset` и `pageXOffset`).

### Пример получения координат элемента относительно всей страницы:

```js
function getCoords(elem) {
  let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: Math.round(box.top + pageYOffset),
    left: Math.round(box.left + pageXOffset)
  };
}


let testBlock = document.querySelector('.testBlock');
let counter = 0;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  console.log('Страница загружена');
  e.target.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    counter++;
    console.log('Страница прокручена ' + counter + ' раз');
    console.log('Top: ' + getCoords(testBlock).top);
    console.log('Left: ' + getCoords(testBlock).left);
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.testBlock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200%;
  margin: 150px 10px 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="testBlock">

</div>
```

Как видно из примера, положение элемента при скролле относительно всей страницы остается неизменным. Подробнее о работе с координатами можете прочитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates-document#getCoords).

Answer (score 1):

Подробно здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates-document

```js
let block = document.getElementById('block');

function getCoords(block) {
  let box = block.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };
}
getCoords(block);
console.log(getCoords(block));
```

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 50px 0 0 150px;
}
```

```html
<p id="block"></p>
```